# Select random database records between subset of records having the same count(*) in a query

Tags: mysql, group-by, order-by, random

I have this simple query:

```
  SELECT `value`, count(*) as `noHits` 
    FROM `topic` 
    WHERE identifier IN ('" . implode("','", array_keys($processedIdentifier)) ."') 
    GROUP BY `value` 
    ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 150
```

It generates a list of records such as:

```
keyword1, 100
keyword2, 90
keyword3, 40
keyword4, 40
keyword5, 40
keyword6, 40
...
keyword1500, 40
```

My challenge is to select a list of top 150 records `ordered by count(*) DESC` however when there are more than 1 value having the same count(*) as in the list above keyword3 to keyword1500 select them randomly from the database.

It seems as if the selection is not random from the tests I made.

The result is used to generate a wordcloud and I do not want the same keywords to always be selected (out of thousands) when they have the same count(*)

Comment: In the database there could be 1500 keywords from keyword3 to keyword1500 all having value 40. It would be great to have MySQL select a random number of these keywords to populate the remaining list of the selected top 150 records.. So 1+2 are given but 3-150 should be selected out of 1500 keywords randomly..

Comment: `ORDER BY COUNT(*), RAND() LIMIT 150`

Comment: One Answer is "too complex" (and it admits such).  One answer fails to start with the given `SELECT`, but instead assumes a temp table.  @Akina should present is 'trivial' modification as an Answer, not just a Comment.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this I did the following (see the fiddle)

Created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE test  -- 22 records
(
  the_word TEXT,
  no_of_times INTEGER
);
```

Populated it with the data at the end of this answer.

Then ran the following query:

```
SELECT the_word, no_of_times FROM test
ORDER BY no_of_times DESC, RAND() LIMIT 15;
```

I tested this several times and obtained results like the following. The first 6 records were always the same - keywords1-6. The remaining 9 records were always randomly from keyword7-22.

Result (sample - first 10 shown):

```
 the_word   no_of_times
keyword1            100
keyword2             90
keyword3             80
keyword4             70
keyword5             60
keyword6             50
keyword17            40
keyword19            40
keyword22            40
keyword18            40
```

This is considerably more elegant than my [first answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/249316/34007) - guess I overcomplicated things!:-)

=========================== Data (22 records) ================

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword1',  100);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword2',  90);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword3',  80);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword4',  70);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword5',  60);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword6',  50);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword7',  40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword8',  40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword9',  40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword10', 40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword11', 40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword12', 40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword13', 40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword14', 40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword15', 40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword16', 40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword17', 40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword18', 40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword19', 40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword20', 40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword21', 40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword22', 40);
```

Comment: Final comment in this thread! :-) I've done up another [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=e8ab9cdf59763ab737b20a72a1b5c7d0) with two ways that COUNT(*) and SUM(no_of_times) can be used to perform the calculations - it is predicated on a slightly different interpretation of your original data which I believe is what Akina was thinking? At bottom of fiddle!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is far too complex - might be good for learning about CTEs, but check my much more elegant answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/249346/34007).

This proved to be quite tricky - it involves chaining [`CTE`](https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-common-table-expressions-ctes/)s (Common Table Expressions - aka the [`WITH clause`](https://modern-sql.com/feature/with) - an excelent site). It was made all the more difficult because of the fact that one isn't allowed to put SQL expressions into `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses - the solution would have been considerably easier and more elegant.

I'll explain the logic that I used as I go along - there's a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b6ecd662167a7c4ff9c4b1ce9b8502b0) available here - you'll need `MySQL 8` for Window (or Analytic) function. As I mentioned, I chained a series of `CTE`s so I'll go through the process step by step.

First, I created and populated a table - see the bottom of this answer for that data or the fiddle.

Then I ran this:

```
WITH cte1 AS
(
  SELECT 15 AS tot_num_recs_wanted  -- the 15 could come from a table
),
cte2 AS
(
  SELECT 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY no_of_times DESC) AS rn
  FROM test
)
SELECT * FROM cte2;
```

Result:

```
the_word    no_of_times     rn
keyword1   100  1
keyword2    90  2
keyword3    80  3
keyword4    70  4
keyword5    60  5
keyword6    50  6
keyword7    40  7
keyword8    40  8
keyword9    40  9
keyword10   40  10
-- further data snipped for brevity - see fiddle

-- this could have been made much easier if 
-- could have used SQL in the LIMIT and OFFSET clauses
-- There would have been no need to use (another) CTE
-- or the ROW_NUMBER() Window function.
```

So, we can see that we require 15 records. So, we need to select the first 6 by default (no_of_times 50 - 100) and then 9 records randomly from the remaining 22 (no_of_times = 40).

```
-- above snipped, again for brevity
cte3 AS
(
  SELECT rn, no_of_times nt
  FROM cte2
  WHERE rn = (SELECT tot_num_recs_wanted FROM cte1)
)
SELECT * FROM cte3;
```

Result:

```
rn  nt
15  40
```

So, we know that we require 15 records and the cutoff is 40.

Then I ran:

```
...snipped...
cte4 AS
(
  SELECT 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND()) AS rand_rn
    FROM test
  WHERE no_of_times = (SELECT nt FROM cte3) -- i.e. 40
)
SELECT * FROM cte4;
```

Result:

```
the_word    no_of_times     rand_rn
keyword22   40  1
keyword11   40  2
keyword9    40  3
keyword8    40  4
keyword10   40  5
keyword16   40  6
keyword7    40  7
keyword15   40  8
keyword13   40  9
keyword21   40  10
-- snipped...
```

So, now I have the 16 records that have no_of_times that are equal to 40 and, **more importantly** ordered using the `RAND()` function.

Then, I select from that table using this SQL:

```
, cte5 AS
(
  SELECT * FROM cte4
  WHERE rand_rn <= (SELECT tot_num_recs_wanted FROM cte1) 
               - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE no_of_times > (SELECT nt FROM cte3))
)
SELECT * FROM cte5;
-- again, this could have been made much easier if 
-- could have used SQL in the LIMIT and OFFSET clauses
-- There would have been no need to use (another) CTE
-- or the ROW_NUMBER() Window function.
```

Result:

```
the_word    no_of_times     rand_rn
keyword9    40  1
keyword18   40  2
keyword12   40  3
keyword11   40  4
keyword13   40  5
keyword22   40  6
keyword19   40  7
keyword15   40  8
keyword10   40  9
-- **__9 rows__** --
```

9 rows + the 6 that have `no_of_points` greater than 40 gives the 15 required rows.

The key part of the above SQL is:

```
WHERE rand_rn <= (SELECT tot_num_recs_wanted FROM cte1) 
                   - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE no_of_times > (SELECT nt FROM cte3))
```

This is 15 - 6 which is 9 - exactly what we needed for the random component of our records.

And finally, I ran a [`UNION`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) between my random records and the ones with `no_of_points` above 40 like this:

```
SELECT the_word, no_of_times FROM cte5
UNION 
SELECT the_word, no_of_times FROM test
WHERE no_of_times > (SELECT nt FROM cte3)
ORDER BY no_of_times DESC;
```

Result:

```
the_word    no_of_times
keyword1    100
keyword2    90
keyword3    80
keyword4    70
keyword5    60
keyword6    50
keyword11   40
keyword14   40
keyword21   40
-- snipped --
```

The first 6 keywords are invariant, but if you run the fiddle several times, you will see that the keywords > 6 (i.e. `no_of_points` =  40) change on each run.

I'm not sure how efficient this solution is, but suitable indexes might help. I hope this answers your question - if not let me know. p.s. welcome to the forum!  :-)

============================== Table and data ======================

```
CREATE TABLE test  -- 22 records
(
  the_word TEXT,
  no_of_times INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword1',  100);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword2',  90);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword3',  80);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword4',  70);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword5',  60);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword6',  50);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword7',  40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword8',  40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword9',  40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword10', 40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword11', 40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword12', 40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword13', 40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword14', 40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword15', 40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword16', 40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword17', 40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword18', 40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword19', 40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword20', 40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword21', 40);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('keyword22', 40);
```

Comment: Thanks @Vérace for a really cool solution and for the welcome. I too thought it might be trickier than what first appears. We will test your implementation later. Unfortunately in our current production environment we still run MySQL 5.5.62-0+deb8u1 - (Debian),,, so we would need to wait before we can implement it..

Comment: It appears that I spoke too soon. It appears that a modified version of Akina's solution works nicely on 5.6 - see the fiddle [here]( https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=7fa12f8075ba56627b118d9fe05f1db3). Yhould still get version 8 though :-)

Comment: Simply adding RAND() after COUNT() in order does not work in our enivronment.. please see screen shots here: https://imgur.com/a/Dv668NU?

ping @Vèrace

Comment: It's in the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=b62de31b6b5c215616f27fa5e1303e69) - as I said, I had to modify the orignal! It's the first SQL after the table definition and the data - multiply tested! I can write it up as a new answer if you like?

Comment: It is fine - no need - I tried again in our environment and now it seems fine when adding the RAND() after COUNT(*) DESC.. strange however we will later validate with our solution that the keywords are in order and inline with your fiddle and Akinas solution.